# Dual Windows + Luks Lubuntu on same HDD. No password on boot

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, encryption

I installed Lubuntu Luks in the second partition of my HD0

Yet I don't understand why I have to enter the password just after turning on the computer, the first partition still contains an unencrypted Windows OS and I want to access that without any password

Any way to input password only after choosing and starting Lubuntu?

Comment: You haven't provided any release details and thus I have no idea which installer you used. It'll be easier if your `/boot/` is unencrypted (*then yes you can*) but *modern* releases encrypt `/boot` thus what's there requires you enter passphrase first (*it maybe possible without but its more complex*)  If using uEFI to boot you shouldn't need a key as the firmware can select OS and not grub (grub's code being inside /boot)

Comment: hey thanks, I'm using the Calamares installer that goes with Lubuntu 22.04

Comment: You're using Grub to select OS, aren't you? There's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to input password only after choosing and starting Lubuntu?

No, for obvious reasons.

As with most, almost all, Windows-Linux dual-boot arrangement the OS selection is enabled by [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) wich is "part of" Lubuntu in this case, not Windows. As such it needs to read from the encrypted partition. The only exception would be, as previously mentioned in comments, having a separated and unencrypted `/boot` partition and such scenario is quite atypical nowadays (and must be "manually" setup).

The only way to work around this is to boot Windows directly via UEFI settings > Boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs.

I tried having /boot in a different unencrypted partition but it seems lubuntu and the installer Calamares have some problem to finish the set up correctly, either the bootloader won't install or it won't give me an option to decrypt the encrypted / at boot. I tried to fix this in different ways but nothing

In the end I had to use a different distro with ubiquity installer, then I was able to install the /boot in an unencrypted partition and have the bootloader the way I wanted

So much time I spent with this that I'm already regretting

Comment: /root?   The `/root` is a directory and usually on KB in size, so it's extremely rare for it to have it's own partition.  You realize `/` and `/root` are different; `/root` is a user directory for the root user, where as `/` is the root directory.

Comment: Also FYI:  the `ubiquity` installer uses an older encryption script & doesn't encrypt /boot by default (*that needs to be done manually as per documentation if required; `calamares` uses the newer/*higher standard* encryption script by default also found on canary installer that will replace ubiquity when it's ready*)

Comment: yeap I guess I meant / and not /root, I already edited that

either way I wasn't able to use calamares to have the booting I wanted, gave up on that, it's ignorance, lack of expertise and time and whatsoever but I don't think it's worth sparing more time with it